# pyopt nsga2 terminated abnormally

Tags: python

I install pyopt through this command below in annaconda:

```
conda install --channel https://conda.anaconda.org/melund pyopt
```

it successfully installs pyopt. Then I run a test.py below

```
import pyopt
from pyopt import  NSGA2
for i in range(2):
    #here is a opt_prob definition
    nsga=NSGA2()
    nsga(opt_prob)
    print opt_prob.solution(0)
```

it does work in the first loop.But in the second loop, when i=1, the python.exe exits surprisingly. I've searched all the probs about pyopt ,however nothing could be found.